# Searching a 2 exact string in complete line using python

Tags: python-2.7

```
f=open('log.txt','r')
lines = f.read()
match = re.findall('("created_at":"(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})").*("status":"[A-Z]+")' , lines)
for out in match:
        print out
```

log.txt contains :

```
[{"build_id":13368,"name":"product-hyd-ML-1072","created_at":"2018-08-04 01:25:54","branch_name":"RSSE_10GSFU_PRODUCT","branch_id":"4850","status":"FAILURE","pipeline_status":"SUCCESS"},{"build_id":13353,"name":"product-hyd-ML-1071","created_at":"2018-08-03 21:25:20","branch_name":"RSSE_10GSFU_PRODUCT","branch_id":"4850","status":"FAILURE","pipeline_status":"SUCCESS"},{"build_id":13265,"name":"product-hyd-ML-1070","created_at":"2018-08-03 16:27:14","branch_name":"RSSE_10GSFU_PRODUCT","branch_id":"4850","status":"FAILURE","pipeline_status":"SUCCESS"}]
```

Comment: Please format your code. See [How do I format code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361)

Comment: Also the body should contain the question, not just the title.

Comment: You should use a JSON parser here, I think, because you're searching JSON.

Comment: So what's the question?